# KOMA scrlttr2 margin notes

Tags: layout

some newbie here that started to learn LaTeX.

I am currently exploring KOMA scrlttr2. For this I tried recreating the following letter but got some problems while doing so:

I cannot work out how to achieve those margin notes like those marked by a red box in the image. I tried using addmargin but this completely crushes the layout (especially the layout of the location var)

I appreciate any help.

You can find the email I try to recreate here: https://wikileaks.org/bnd-inquiry/docs/MAD/MAT%20A%20MAD-2b.pdf

Thanks,

Dave

---

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside, ngerman, firsthead=false]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Arial}
    \setmonofont{Courier New}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\KOMAoption{locfield}{wide}

\setkomavar{location}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \sffamily\raggedright\par
    \fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont
    \Ifkomavarempty{fromname}{}{\textbf{\usekomavar{fromname}}\\[1.5pt]}
    \jobtitle\\[1.5pt]
    \vspace{1em}
    \Ifkomavarempty{fromaddress}{}{\usekomavar{fromaddress}\\[1.5pt]}
    \Ifkomavarempty{fromzipcode}{}{\usekomavar{fromzipcode}\\[1.5pt]}
    \vspace{1em}
    \Ifkomavarempty{fromphone}{}{\usekomavar{fromphone}\\[1.5pt]}
    \Ifkomavarempty{fromfax}{}{\usekomavar{fromfax}\\[1.5pt]}
    \Ifkomavarempty{fromemail}{}{\usekomavar{fromemail}\\[1.5pt]}
}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Bundesministerium~der~Verteidigung,~11055~Berlin}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\newcommand{\jobtitle}{Beauftragter~des~Bundesministeriums~der\\Verteidigung~im~1.~Untersuchungsausschuss~der\\18.~Wahlperiode}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Stauffenbergstraße~18,~10785~Berlin}
\setkomavar{fromzipcode}{11055~Berlin}

\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49~(0)12~34-56-7890}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{+49~(0)12~34-567890}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{BMVgBeaUANSA@BMVg.Bund.de}

\setkomavar{subject}{My Subject}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{RECIPIENT}
    
    \opening{Opening}

    Text...

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

### Status Quo

[image: Status Quo]

### Goal

[image: Goal]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not a user of the KOMA classes, but I don't see the elements you've marked as being margin notes.  Instead, I interpret them as elements that are attached to the main text by shoving them off to the left at the beginning of the line.  (They may fall into the formal margin, but not always.)  I'd approach this by looking at how `\llap` might be applied, on a line-by-line basis.